# Objective-C: How can I freeze the screen and add loading animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, loading, freeze

I made an application which download lots of data and I want to add some animation why it is loading and freeze the screen.
I have already find function which work but it only freeze button
function:

```
[super setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = !editing;
```

I' ve seen some application which already use this kind of animation.the image should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSURLDownload for asynchronous downloads, there is a delegate method which you cane use to determine the progress.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLDownload_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Then using a NSProgressIndicator you can display the progress the same way that image of yours does.

Comment: but i use   
 theRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
 [theRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];
 [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData]; 
 [theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
 
 theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
  xmlFile = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

Comment: Can I just simply make the animation?

Comment: @Csabi thats what you got NSProgressIndicator for :)

Answer (score 2):

I found something

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD